# heatmap2 lmat,lhei, lwid parameters?

Tags: r, heatmap

I'm trying to make a heat map with dendrogram in R. I'm also trying to make it so that the color matrix is on the bottom of the heat map. i understand that I would have to change the value of lmat for this. So far I have something like this for lmat.

```
 lmat=rbind(c(0,3,0), c(2,1,0), c(0,4,0)).
```

After I run it, it asks me to update the lhei and lwid values. After looking at the documentation, I understand that these are vectors for column width and row height. But I don't understand the multiple values needed for their values. For ex, when I set this , I get this error.

```
  lhei must have length = nrow(lmat) = 3
```

I'm not sure what the three values for lhei would correspond to. This leads me to a broader question, what does each value in the vectors for lhei and lwid correspond to?

Answer (score 5):

`lhei` is the relative heights of the rows in the plot. Heatmaps in R are a bit screwy. The graphics device (think of a canvas you want to paint on) is divided into a grid where each element of the heatmap will be plotted: color key, dendrograms and the heatmap. This makes a 2x2 grid. when you add the colsideColors or rowsidecolors the grid expands by 1 in the appropriate dimension, (e.g. 1 more row when adding colsidecolors). When you add this extra row you need to tell R how much (relative) space it needs.

```
mat <- matrix(rnorm(200), nrow = 20)
colCols <- rep(c("red", "blue"), 5)
heatmap.2(mat, trace="none", ColSideColors = colCols,
          lmat=rbind(c(5,4), c(3,2), c(0,1)),
          lhei=c(2,4,0.2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

lmat stands for layout matrix, and in heatmap.2 the default is a 2x2 matrix used to organize four components (1=heatmap, 2=row dendogram, 3=col dendogram, 4= key ) as follows: 
lmat = rbind(c(4,3),c(2,1))
Your error, "lhei must have length = nrow(lmat) = 3" arises because you need to specify the new lhei or layout row heights, which from your code is now 3 rows. Visually it helps to organize this code in stacked format. In your example I can clearly see that the key will be below the heatmap, while the zeros are used as padding.